# Where are good dive sites to scuba dive with seahorses?

Tags: scuba-diving, dive-sites

In a couple of weeks my buddy (husband) and I will be doing a few dives on the UK's Jurassic coastline, in Swanage.

It's said if the vis (visibility) is good here you can often see seahorses, as they are doing well in the neighbouring bay at Studland.

British water is infamous for it's vis, and not always positively - **where are some good dive sites globally to dive with seahorses?**

Include in this, a depth of 25m (82 feet) or less, for shore dives only (around 15m (50 ft) from land).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seahorses are found all over the world where they :

> Diving with Seahorses: seahorses inhabit coral reefs and sea grass beds. They have been recorded at depths as low as 0.5m and as deep as 75m.

Also:

> Dive Report: Seahorses are mainly found in shallow tropical and temperate waters throughout the world, and prefer to live in sheltered areas such as sea grass beds, estuaries, coral reefs, or mangroves.

Global dive sites include:

1. Indonesia - Wakatobi Dive Resort
2. West Papua - Raja Ampat
3. Papua New Guinea - Milne Bay
4. Solomon Islands
5. Sulawesi - Lembeh Strait
6. United States - [Blue Heron Bridge](http://www.puravidadivers.com/dive-blue-heron-bridge-phil-foster-park), Foster Park, Florida

The website [Dive Report - Seahorses](http://www.divereport.com/animals/seahorse/) - gives a whooping list of dive sites for seahorses and a multitude of other marine life you can find alongside them.

[Diving with Seahorses - dive the world](http://www.dive-the-world.com/creatures-seahorses.php)

[5 of the best places to dive with seahorses - uw360asia](https://www.uw360.asia/best-places-dive-pygmy-seahorses/)